# How to increase the font size of the tables contents in latex?

Tags: tables, floats

The MWE is as follows. When I compile the below mentioned code it results in correct output, but the generated output is very tiny. Is there any way to increase the font size of the table cells, while maintaining all the contents. Any help is appreciated.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\tcaption{Descriptive statistics of some numerical variables of the used dataset.}
\label{t0}

\scalebox{0.52}
{

\begin{tabular}{llccccccc}
\hline
Variable name & Variable description & N & Missing & Mean & Median & Std. Dev. & Min & Max\\
\hline
Actual\_Effort (in PM) & Total development effort (in PM) & 10 & 0 & 7014.91 & 3363.47 & 7931.52 & 377.8 & 22479.3\\
No.of.Processes & Total number of processes for an application & 10 & 0 & 2.9 & 2.5 & 1.96 & 1 & 7\\
No.of.Tasks & Total number of tasks for processes & 10 & 0 & 6.9 & 5.5 & 4.58 & 2 & 15\\
TCC & Total size based on the definition of processes and tasks of an application & 10 & 0 & 975.7 & 539 & 1027.62 & 74 & 2890\\  
\hline\\

\end{tabular}
}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Please eliminate unproductive guesswork as to which packages might define which macros (e.g., `\scalebox` and `\tcaption`). Ideally, you would provide all commands that make the code fully compilable right away -- including information about the width of the the text block, the font size, and the font itself.

Comment: @Mico. Fine. \tcaption can not be eliminated as the same is provided by the journal template. But when I eliminate the \scalebox then the contents of tables are scattered.

Comment: Please note that I did *not* ask you to eliminate `\thead`. Instead, do provide information about the template you're using. Presumably, the template either defines the macro `\thead` itself or loads a pakage that defines `\thead`.

Comment: Journal is Journal of Web Engineering.

Comment: why have you got `\scalebox{0.52}` around the table if you don't want to shrink the fonts to an impossibly small to read  size?

Answer (score 1):

This could help you :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin={1cm,1cm}]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
  \caption{Descriptive statistics of some numerical variables of the used dataset.}
  \label{t0}

  \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{5cm}ccccccc}
    \hline
    Variable name & Variable description & N & Missing & Mean & Median & Std. Dev. & Min & Max\\
    \hline
    Actual\_Effort (in PM) & Total development effort (in PM) & 10 & 0 & 7014.91 & 3363.47 & 7931.52 & 377.8 & 22479.3\\
    No.of.Processes & Total number of processes for an application & 10 & 0 & 2.9 & 2.5 & 1.96 & 1 & 7\\
    No.of.Tasks & Total number of tasks for processes & 10 & 0 & 6.9 & 5.5 & 4.58 & 2 & 15\\
    TCC & Total size based on the definition of processes and tasks of an application & 10 & 0 & 975.7 & 539 & 1027.62 & 74 & 2890\\  
    \hline\\

  \end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But how to do this without adjusting the margins and setting the page as A4. If we adjust the page size this will violate the journal regulations.

Comment: @SibaMishra, what do you exactly do ? If you want to increase the font size, it will ake more place. You must reduce the witdth of the columns using p parameter

Comment: @SibaMishra, provide us a complete compilable example

Comment: when i used your above mentioned tricks i got the following output. The print screen is attached

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `\small` as font size, and `tabularx`. I loaded the `caption` package for a better vertical skip between caption and table, `booktabs` to have some padding around horizontal rules and `makecell` for line breaks in ordinary cells. Finally I slightly reduced the value of `tabcolsep`. Comment aside: you should load the `french` option of babel via the documentclass options.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, caption, makecell, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \caption{Descriptive statistics of some numerical variables of the used dataset.}
  \label{t0}
  \small
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l>{\raggedright}X*{7}{c}@{}}%
    \toprule
    Variable name & \makecell{Variable description} & N & Missing & Mean & Median & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\
    \midrule
 \makecell[lt]{Actual\_Effort \\ (in PM)} &{Total development effort\\ (in PM)} & 10 & 0 & 7014.91 & 3363.47 & 7931.52 & 377.8 & 22479.3\\
 No.of.Processes & {Total number of processes\\ for an application} & 10 & 0 & 2.9 & 2.5 & 1.96 & 1 & 7\\
 No.of.Tasks & Total number of tasks for processes & 10 & 0 & 6.9 & 5.5 & 4.58 & 2 & 15 \\
 TCC & Total size based on the definition of processes and tasks of an application & 10 & 0 & 975.7 & 539 & 1027.62 & 74 & 2890 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]